# DAX/Power BI: How can I filter distinct rows conditionally on two (or more) columns?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have an event log that records timestamps of various events for all user sessions. Each session can have many log events with different event types, as below:

| sessionID | time | eventType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 5:01:10 | ready |
| 001 | 5:01:14 | denied |
| 001 | 5:01:19 | success |
| 002 | 5:05:00 | ready |
| 003 | 5:06:14 | ready |
| 003 | 5:06:19 | denied |
| 002 | 5:07:20 | success |

I need to find the count of only the *latest* event for each session. I got to:

```
deniedCount = COUNTAX(FILTER('sessions',
    [eventType] = "denied"
), [time])
```

but this counts sessionID 001, since it had a denied event. Since that session ended on a success, it should not be included. What expressions could do this type of unique filtering? Thanks.

Comment: What is your expected output that will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is finding the maximal time for each session.

This is the simplest version that occurs to me:

```
deniedCount =
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        sessions,
        sessions[time]
            = CALCULATE (
                MAX ( sessions[time] ),
                ALLEXCEPT ( sessions, sessions[sessionID] )
            )
            && sessions[eventType] = "denied"
    )
)
```

This counts the rows where the time is the latest one for that session and then type is "denied".

Though straightforward, this is not the most efficient since it requires computing the maximum for each row of `sessions`. A more efficient approach would be to group first so that you're iterating over a smaller table:

```
deniedCount =
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        SUMMARIZE ( sessions, sessions[sessionID], "LastTime", MAX ( sessions[time] ) ),
        CALCULATE (
            SELECTEDVALUE ( sessions[eventType] ),
            sessions[time] = EARLIER ( [LastTime] )
        ) = "denied"
    )
)
```